# What's the meaning of "More than 53 percent of those in their 30s followed suit" in this article?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> The number of working women who got married posted 5.6 million as of
>   this year, the report showed. About 45 percent of them stopped working
>   due to the burdens of juggling work, child care and house affairs.
>   **More than 53 percent of those in their 30s followed suit.**

link: http://koreajoongangdaily.joins.com/news/article/article.aspx?aid=3012496

I know the meaning of the phrase "follow suit" is to follow in the same pattern.
Still, I'm not sure about the meaning or intention of the last sentence in the article above?

The author wanted to emphasize that compared to the rate of general population of working women, 45 percent, women working in their 30s showed higher quit rate(53%)?

Comment: I suspect your example wasn't written by a native Anglophone (unless ***posted*** is a simple typo; normally I would expect ***passed***). It's also a *very* odd use of the idiomatic ***follow suit***, which again is probably down to the writer being nns rather than "creative".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the author is trying to show that **disproportionate** number of **married working women** in their 30's, **over half**, left the workforce compared to the **total population of married working women**, which was **less than half**, that left the workforce.

This is understandable since younger children require greater attention, and there is a **correlation** between younger children and younger mothers.

What is not known is the **proportion** of 30 year olds in the total population of married working women.